# CSS transform transition not working on Android browser

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm developing a little website:

http://richacinas.github.io

When I open it from Android Browser, and tap on the hamburger menu, it doesn't animate the UL element that brings all the options.

It works on any other browser/device/screen size but it just doesn't on Android Browser.

I use a translateX. I checked and it is supported on pretty much any browser. This UL is position: fixed.

Anyone could please help? Here is some code:

```
<input id="cab_especial_button" type="checkbox" name="cab_especial_button">

<ul class="nav principal">
          <li class="l1">
            <a href="...">text
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="l2">
              <a href="...">text</a>
          </li>
</ul>

<style>
#cab_especial_button:checked ~ .nav.principal{
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 700ms ease;
            transition:transform 700ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
            transform: translateX(0%);
}
.nav.principal{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    /*right:-100%;*/
    width: 40%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    padding:1em;
    overflow:auto;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 700ms ease;
            transition:transform 700ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should include some code and a clear example of your problem.

Comment: I edit the question so you can see some code. Thanks in advance!! by the way, I just realized that when I hit the checkbox (hidden behind a hamburger icon), and then I hit the browser bar as if I was going to type in a different url, then the translateX works.

Comment: And I see the menu smoothly change it position to where I want it to be.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this problem. My android version is 4.1.2. Any help would be much appreciated...